# Can I disable Werror from the commandline

Tags: cmake

I have a library that I downloaded, and I'd rather not edit its CMakeLists.txt because I'd have remember to do that for any future version.

This library adds `-Werror` to each compile line, and my compiler complains about something: it gives a hint `suggest putting braces around whatever`. Something harmless.

So I want to disable `Werror` from the cmake commandline. I found the existence of a `CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR` variable, but my attempts to `-D CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR=OFF` did not change the situation.

Is there a way out for me, short of explicitly setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`?

(It looks like all seemingly relevant answers to this on SO assume I have a CMakeLists.txt that I can edit.)

Comment: By setting `CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR` to ON you tell CMake to *additionally* pass `-Werror` option for the compiler. But setting this variable to OFF doesn't tell CMake to look into every command line and remove the option from it. If a library specifies `-Werror` in the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS as **CACHE variable**, then passing `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` could change that setting, but it is unlikely that a library sets exactly CACHE variant of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. Generally, you cannot easily remove a thing which is set explicitly in the `CMakeLists.txt`. You need to modify that `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Is this a project you could report an issue to or even an open source project where you could contribute the fix? If that is the case I'd recommend creating an issue plus potentially a pull request with a fix e.g. `set(SOME_PROJECT_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR On CACHE BOOL "treat warnings as errors") set(CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNINGS_AS_ERROR "${SOME_PROJECT_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR }")` should be a fix for the issue that should work, whether the project on it's own or separately. Alternatively (or in addition to this) just fix the compiler warnings...

Comment: Just edit the CMakeLists.txt of the library in question, and save yourself the trouble

Comment: I love that word "just". This is a big project with very complicated CMake setups. @nega

Comment: So complicated that you can't edit one text file to remove one compiler option? Why do you want to create more work for yourself?